# I get this "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, addition

I can't figure out why I keep getting this error. Whenever I press the button in my app the whole thing crashes. Here is the code:

```
#import "additionViewController.h"

@interface additionViewController (){
}

@end

@implementation additionViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)getValue: (id)sender {
    self.numberOne = (NSNumber *)self.firstNum.text;
    self.numberTwo = (NSNumber *)self.secondNum.text;
    self.fnumberOne = [self.numberOne floatValue];
    self.fnumberTwo = [self.numberTwo floatValue];

    self.finalValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(self.fnumberOne + self.fnumberTwo)];

    self.sum.text = (NSString *)self.finalValue;


}
@end
```

This is the first iOS app I'm trying to make by myself. It's pretty simple. Not going on the App Store or anything.

Comment: Error message, please.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming firstNum and secondNum are UITextFields - the `text` properties of those objects will be `NSStrings`. You can't convert them to numbers by doing a cast to `NSNumber`. This will just change the type of the pointer but do nothing to actually convert the representation of the data from text to a number.

The simplest solution is:

```
self.fnumberOne = self.firstNum.floatValue;
self.fnumberTwo = self.secondNum.floatValue;
```

The `floatValue` properties will actually convert the text to a `float`. Then perhaps you don't even need the `self.numberOne` and `self.numberTwo` properties? If you still do, you can do this (and similarly with self.finalNumber if you need that too):

```
self.fnumberOne = self.firstNum.floatValue;
self.fnumberTwo = self.secondNum.floatValue;
self.numberOne = @(self.fnumberOne);
self.numberTwo = @(self.fnumberTwo);
```

The `@()` syntax is a convenient way to wrap a primitive in its associated object type, in this case a `NSNumber`.

Also, you'll have a simlar problem with `self.sum.text = (NSString *)self.finalValue` - you can't use a C casting operator, you need to actually convert the value back to a string. Simple solution is:

```
self.sum.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", self.fnumberOne + self.fnumberTwo];
```

There are more advanced ways to convert to/from numeric values using [`NSNumberFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html), etc., if you need more robust support. There's plenty of documentation on that.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that solution didn't work. Your advice actually did help both for this and for the future, but the same error comes up.

Comment: In that case we'll need some more details about the actual error. For example set an exception breakpoint as suggested by @Kevin

Comment: I did. I looks like the problem is with the button. Otherwise, it doesn't crash.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the project navigator (left window) and go into the breakpoints tab (looks like a carrot) then add an exception breakpoint. This breakpoint should show you where the crash occured. I suspect the problem is trying to cast an NSString to an NSNumber. Use intValue, floatValue, or doubleValue instead.

Answer (score -1):

you need to deallocate the memory you used for these variables

```
release variableName;
```

for example, Im not sure what type numberOne, and numberTwo are